# Как поставить сглаживание шрифтов в WebStorm 2016?

Tags: webstorm

Как убрать это ужасное отрисовывание кавычек у тегов? Причем плохо отрисовываются не только эти кавычеи, но и в целом все.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что по какой то причине, какой бы я шрифт не выбрал в программе, проблема остается. В настройках ВебШторма перепробовал все настройки Antialiasing. Все только хуже становилось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, просто для сравнения, скриншот из Atom
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ну это же небо и земля! Шрифт и там и там выбрна одни и тот же.

**Система Вин10.**

UPD
Во избежании недоразумений, на скриншоте с Atom размер шрифта 14px. Прилагаю скриншот из WebStorm c размером шрифта 14px. Так же линии знаков дерганные.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Размер шрифта разный. Попробуй немного увеличить.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, я добавил скриншот с таким же размером шрифта. Скобки так и квадратит.

Comment: А случайно не используется openjdk вместо oracle java jdk?

Comment: @KoVadim я бы ответил, но не знаю как проверить, что используется... Не подскажете?

Comment: Не увидел, что в тексте написано что ось - вин. Тогда вряд ли у Вас openjdk.